# TFS build fails because of linker issues

Tags: c++, tfs

I have a combined solution which consists of :

- 3 C# projects
- 2 VB.NET projects
- 18 C++ projects : CLR and MFC combined

The C++ projects depends one on another and they have correctly defined the project dependencies. 
On my local machine the solution compiles on both Debug and Release on both x86 and x64 environment.

However when I upload the code in the TFS build machine, the build fails because of linker issues (some libraries - existing projects that generate these libs - are not found).

From what i read until now it seems that the TFS machine is overriding my $(OutDir) and this is why the TFS build fails.

Are there any workarounds i can use ?

Comment: Are you using XAML build or the newer build system? What version of TFS are you talking about?

Comment: TFS that ships with Visual Studio 2013.

Comment: @Lucian Could you please post the error messages here? In TFS build did you add some msbuild variables? And in the .csproj file, what does the output path?

Comment: The error that i am receiving is the following :   LINK: cannot open input file 'Name.lib' . On my local computer solution is compiling without any error

Comment: Later edit : I managed to fix the problem. I had to add in the Linker -> Additional Library Directories the $(OutDir) macro. For some reason the my path that used $(SolutionDir) was not ok on the TFS machine

Comment: @Lucian Glad to hear that you fixed this issue. Could you please post the solution and mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the problem.

I had to add in the Linker -> Additional Library Directories the $(OutDir) macro.

For some reason my path that used $(SolutionDir) was not ok on the TFS machine